# In dynamoDB, I don't know how to scan low level of attribute

Tags: node.js, amazon-web-services, attributes, amazon-dynamodb, scanning

I'm beginner of dynamoDB
I want to know how solve this problem.
I want get MapInfo.MapX value(I want to get low level attribute of MapInfo)

```
const params = {
        TableName: "ZzimCuration",
        ProjectionExpression: "Id, Knock, Modified, MapInfo.MapX"
    }
    dynamo.doc.scan(params, (err, data) => {
        if(err){
            console.error("No Scan : " ,JSON.stringify(err, null, 2))
        } else{
            console.log(data);
```

but results like this

```
{ 
   Knock: 3811,
   Id: 'tour.2029011',
   Modified: 20161201153517,
   MapInfo: [Object] 
}
```

I don't want rebuild json.
How can I get MapInfo.mapX directly???

Comment: what is the dynamodb data type of MapX? Are you expecting some value instead of [Object]?

Comment: By default, console log display only the first level property of objects. Try with `data.MapInfo.MapX`

Comment: ah...  MapX data type is Number and using 'data.MapInfo.MapX' is like rebuild json... I wanna get second property MapX, MapY in MapInfo...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> By default, console log display only the first level property of
>   objects

Change the console log in the `else` statement as mentioned below:-

```
console.log(JSON.stringify(data, null, 2));
```